How to redirect to a specific message in a group on telegram?
I'm coding a python code to retrieve message in all my private groups (there are like 500 message in each group/each hour). So it's impossible for me to read thoses and this is why I need a bot.
I can connect with TelegramClient() so I can read every new message that is posted in my groups.
Sometimes I want to get a fast access to one of theses messages (reference) so I also use telegram-bot with a token to send me a private message with a link to that message.
The problem is: I cannot make any link to work.
I tried this at first:
message_link = f"https://t.me/c/{(chat_id)}/{message_id}"
await bot.send_message(chat_id=your_chat_id, text=f"Price found: {current_number} in group '{chat_name}' at this link {message_link}.")

here the problem is that this open up a browser (so it quit my telegram app) and it redirect on telegram.org
so I tried this one:
message_link = f"tg://resolve?domain={(chat_id)}&message_id={message_id}"
await bot.send_message(chat_id=your_chat_id, text=f"Price found: {current_number} in group '{chat_name}' at this link {message_link}.")

And this tell me "this user does not exist", i just want to get a fast access to a specific message in a group why does it speak about a user ?
To help, this is the kind of value I get for chat_id and message_id:
chat_id="-1112204423696"
message_id="302254"

As you can see the chat id is negative which mean this is a private group.
Could it be that the groups disabled link access to specific message ?
EDIT: I also just tried the following (nothing is hapenning when i click on the link)
message_link = f"tg://openmessage?chat_id={chat_id}&message_id={message_id}"

